Azure Pipeline fails to checkout a submodule
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that should run for every push on the master branch. My repository has a submodule defined:
[submodule "submodules/shared_components"]
    path = submodules/shared_components
    url = ../shared_components

The submodule is basically checked out (when using git clone <link> --recurse-submodules -j8) and everything works fine. However, my Azure pipeline is unable to do a checkout on the submodule, claiming:
git submodule sync --recursive
git --config-env=http.https://myorg@dev.azure.com.extraheader=env_var_http.https://myorg@dev.azure.com.extraheader submodule update --init --force --depth=1 --recursive
Submodule 'submodules/shared_backend' (https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/MyProject/_git/shared_backend) registered for path 'submodules/shared_backend'
Cloning into '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodules/shared_backend'...
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier shared_backend does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/myorg/MyProject/_git/shared_backend/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/MyProject/_git/shared_backend' into submodule path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodules/shared_backend' failed
Failed to clone 'submodules/shared_backend'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodules/shared_backend'...
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier shared_backend does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/myorg/MyProject/_git/shared_backend/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/MyProject/_git/shared_backend' into submodule path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodules/shared_backend' failed
Failed to clone 'submodules/shared_backend' a second time, aborting
##[error]Git submodule update failed with exit code: 1

Considering the fact that the main repository (the one with the azure-pipeline.yml) gets checked out just fine, it makes no sense to me that the submodule could not be checked out, especially since both repositories are in the same Azure DevOps organization and also in the same project. This is my YAML file:
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- checkout: self
  displayName: 'Checkout'
  submodules: recursive
  persistCredentials: true

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'Dotnet Build $(buildConfiguration)'

I also tried a different approach by creating a PAT with access to repos read and then using that, but to no avail.
- powershell: |
    $header = "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
    git -c http.extraheader="$header" submodule sync
    git -c http.extraheader="$header" submodule update --init --force --depth=1

Am I missing something here?
EDIT: Forgot to post, I've already given the Build Service permissions to access the submodule repository:


After dealing with this for about a day, I managed to find an article named "Dealing with error TF401019 when using submodules in Azure Pipelines" written by Tim Schaeps.
Long story short, cloning submodules from pipelines seems to be disabled for security reasons. I had to disable 3 options for this work (had to disable them on organization level first before I could set a specific value for them in my Azure DevOps project):

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines
Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines


Huge shoutout to Tim Schaeps for the article! You rock!

Thanks a lot for sharing, this also fixed it for me

According to steps.checkout documentation, this might be a permissions issue:

If you're running the agent in the Local Service account and want to modify the current repository by using git operations or loading git submodules, give the proper permissions to the Project Collection Build Service Accounts user.

See also Checkout submodules.

I've given the permission to the "agent user" (which was created by Azure itself) to access the repository(ies), and sadly none of the things mentioned in the documentation actually helped, especially since it uses the same credentials which should mean the submodule clone would work.
